# Send serialized object from server to GWT

Tags: gwt, serialization, deserialization

I'm looking for a easy way to send a custom class from an ActionBean response to a GWT client.

Can someone help me with a easy and concret example how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried, what errors have you had? The standard GWT documentation has a whole section on how to communicate with the server: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication and https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/clientserver look like they might be a good start

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use RequestFactory as it does not require that the bean be serializable as the GWT RPC service does. You would create a value proxy on the client side and make sure it maps getters/setters that you need.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory